# SonarQube - How do I exclude native methods from naming convention rules?

Tags: java, sonarqube, native

We are using SonarQube to analyze our Java project.

When linking to native dynamic libraries, we use c naming conventions (same names as in the .DLL/.dylib APIs) which leads to these "Code Smell"s detected by SonarQube. The docs says that `@Override`en methods are excluded, can we configure `native` method declerations to be excluded as well?

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify whether you're using SonarCFamily, or the Cxx analyzer

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam non of the above, AFAIK. We do not analyze the C/CPP sources, only the Java source.